# Java slick, html cant find AppletLoader

Tags: java, html, applet, slick2d

I have made a java game using slick state based game, as my game extends StatBasedGame it is not a true applet because it doesnt extend JApplet, so to solve that problem there is a method build in with slick which can be used in html.

I had found this link which showed me how to do this: http://ninjacave.com/slickapplet
And did everything it asked me to do, I made a jar file of my game using eclipse (my compiler) , downloaded the latest version lwjgl and modified the code on the website shown above to work with my game:

```
     <applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" 
        archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar" 
        codebase="." 
        width="640" height="480">

  <param name="al_title" value="Ham Blaster"> 
  <param name="al_main" value="org.newdawn.slick.AppletGameContainer"> 
  <param name="game" value="org.javagame.Game">

  <param name="al_jars" value="racegame.jar, lwjgl.jar, slick.jar"> 

  <param name="al_windows" value="windows_natives.jar"> 
  <param name="al_linux" value="linux_natives.jar"> 
  <param name="al_mac" value="macosx_natives.jar"> 

  <param name="separate_jvm" value="true"> 
</applet>
```

I checked inside my lwjgl to find out if there was a AppletLoader class using winrar because the error is saying it cant find it, I went into lwjgl_util_applet.jar and found the following:

> AppletLoader$1.class,AppletLoader$2.clas… to...AppletLoader$6.class and AppletLoader

this means that the AppletLoader is there, so then why am I getting the error?

Could someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting Java Slick game on a website using html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222078/putting-java-slick-game-on-a-website-using-html)